# Post request with body and Image file in Robot framework

Tags: robotframework

I am trying to call a Post request which takes some key-values and files in body.But, Getting 400 bad request. Please let me know what am i missing here.

```
Post request with a Image File
    ${POST_HEADER}=    Create Dictionary  Authorization=Bearer ${token}    Content-Type=applicaion/json
    ${org_post_body}=    Create Dictionary    title= Test Robot Post      isPrivate=true
    ...    description= Test Robot Post Description   associationType=${assn_typ1}
    ...    associationId=${org_id}      
    ${img_file}=    Get File For Streaming Upload      ${CURDIR}\\pic1.jpg
    ${file}=    Create dictionary     files=${img_file}
    ${resp}=    POST On Session    host_server  /api/post/  headers=${POST_HEADER}    json=${org_post_body} files=${file}
    Status Should Be                 200  ${resp}
```

Without attaching imag file, API call is sucessful.Fails only when i try to attach image.
Attached the screenshot from postman where it iss uccesful with body as form-data. Trying to repeat same in robot framework.[Postman success screesnhot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c9jY1.png)

Answer (score 0):

Pleae try puting your ${file} variable into dictionary org_post_body

So you gonna have something like this:

```
${org_post_body}=    Create Dictionary    title= Test Robot Post      isPrivate=true
...    description= Test Robot Post Description   associationType=${assn_typ1}
...    associationId=${org_id}
...    files=${file}
```

And your request will looks like this:

```
${resp}=    POST On Session    host_server  /api/post/  headers=${POST_HEADER}    json=${org_post_body}
```